# Counting special characters as spaces in java

Tags: java, macos

I'm working on MacOS, with JDK 8. 
I want to count the number of special characters in the given string, but in the given code, special characters are counted as spaces. What should I do?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
 String str;
 int lc=0,uc=0,d=0,s=0,spc=0;
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Enter the string:");
 str=sc.nextLine();

 for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
   {
    if(str.charAt(i)>='a' && str.charAt(i)<='z')
    {
    lc++;
    }
    else if(str.charAt(i)>='A' && str.charAt(i)<='Z')
    {
    uc++;
    }
    else if(str.charAt(i)>='0' && str.charAt(i)<='9')
    {
    d++;
    }
    else if(str.charAt(i)>=32)
    {
    s++;
    }
    else if(str.charAt(i)>=33 && str.charAt(i)<=47 || str.charAt(i)==64)
    {
    spc++;
    }
   }
System.out.println("number of small characters in "+str+" are:"+lc);
System.out.println("number of CAPITAL characters in "+str+" are:"+uc);
System.out.println("number of digits in "+str+" are:"+d);
System.out.println("number of Spaces in "+str+" are:"+s);
System.out.println("number of Special characters in "+str+" are:"+spc);
}
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
Enter the string:abc23@#$% 

number of small characters in abc23@#$% are:3

number of CAPITAL characters in abc23@#$% are:0

number of digits in abc23@#$% are:2

number of Spaces in abc23@#$% are:4

number of Special characters in abc23@#$% are:0
```

It should be displaying  4  special characters instead of 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `str.charAt(i)>=32` with `str.charAt(i)==32`

The the output for `"abc23@#$% "` will be:

```
number of small characters in abc23@#$%  are:3
number of CAPITAL characters in abc23@#$%  are:0
number of digits in abc23@#$%  are:2
number of Spaces in abc23@#$%  are:1
number of Special characters in abc23@#$%  are:4
```